# Textview invisible when used together with fragment inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, youtube-data-api, android-constraintlayout

I am using YouTubePlayerFragment as fragment with textview above it. Somehow title gets hidden and there is only white space when rendered. It's clear, that TextView exists there, but it's not shown. I get same effect when I set visibility to invisible.

Now:

[image]

Aim:

[image]

XML of view this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        style="@style/movieTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/details_title_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Trailers"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/details_title_left" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the main activity I use this layout with include tag and change visibility of it on button click.

Comment: You have `android:visibility="invisible"` set on the `TextView` so I would expect it to be invisible...

Comment: That&#39;s just for example. It doesn&#39;t show up without it. I forgot to remove it after screenshot. Question edited.

Comment: Did you make sure that text color and background color in @style/movieTitle are different from each other?

Comment: Yes. Same style is used in another included layout, which shows overview with title "About".

Comment: How do you set the text to be displayed in the `TextView`? Are you sure it is not empty?

Comment: That might be the problem. First I get handle to include view and then search for a view inside it. Is this a wrong way doing it?

Comment: Please edit your original post with the pertinent java code so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are notorious inside constraint layout. Put the `Fragment` inside `FrameLayout` and constraints to it. Also i would suggest to give a fixed height to the FrameLayout or use ratio with `height="0dp"`.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title">
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Happy coding :D